# Is it possible to create a discriminated union using mapped types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following interface `X`:

```
type X = {
  red: number, 
  blue: string
}
```

Is it possible to construct a union type `Y` using mapped types? If not, can it be constructed with other kind of type-level mechanisms?

```
type Y = {
  kind: "red"
  payload: number
} | {
 kind: "blue"
 payload: string
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of the fact that `T[keyof T]` is a union of the values of `T`, whatever `T` is. You can use a mapped type to construct a type whose values are the branches of the union you want:

```
type Y = { [K in keyof X]: {kind: K, payload: X[K]} }[keyof X]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoKUBOEAmAuKAdgK4C2ARhBgDRRpRkA2RE+AzsBgJYEDmKAvihShIUAJoJkUANoBpKNygBrCCAD2AM1gBdfEiXc8UWTTABDEAzVmjMOdv5R+0leq0xtKIA)